# Reusing LLVM module for JITting or not?

Tags: c, llvm, jit

I'm currently building a C library, part of which uses LLVM to JIT new functions now and then. That is, it doesn't JIT all the function it will ever need at one time, but rather discovers from time to time that it requires a new function and JITs it on-demand.

It's my first time using LLVM for this, and while my initial test code seems to work fine, the question on my mind is whether I should reuse the same `LLVMModule` object for all new functions, or generate a new `LLVMModule` for each round of compilation. Are there advantages or disadvantages to either? Is there even a difference (and if not, then what's the `LLVMModule` even for)?

For the record, I'm using the MCJIT of LLVM 3.8, and use `LLVMGetFunctionAddress` on the completed function to cause JITting to happen.